# Not able to reply instagram comments using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, instagram

I am writing a script to automate replies on Instagram to anyone who has a 'pen' in their comment.

The script has to scan every post and reply to those who have a 'pen' keyword in their comments. But whenever I run the Script, I faced a problem where the script only scans the first comment and only reply to that, then switches to the next post. But the motive is to read all the comments reply to them. I have attached the script that I used.

```
href_found = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
pic_href = [ele.get_attribute('href') for ele in href_found if '.com/p' in ele.get_attribute('href')]
for ele in pic_href:
    driver.get(ele)
    time.sleep(3)

    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='C4VMK'][contains(., 'Hello')]")
        replybox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='FH9sR'][contains(.,'Reply')])[2]")
        replybox.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        commentbox = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea")
        commentbox().click()
        for i in comment:
            commentbox().send_keys(i)
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,7)/30)
        commentbox().send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    else:
        continue
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(., 'pen')]")
```